# How to write a sql Like statement with a variable init

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am trying to concat my php variable with "LIKE" Statement

I am using this query right now

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM roll_header where contract_no like concat '%'$ContractNo'%' ORDER BY timedate DESC";
```

i have also used something like

```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM roll_header where contract_no like  '%'{$ContractNo}'%' ORDER BY timedate DESC";
```

The purpose of this string is that whatever user writes it gives back all the matching strings

Comment: What is the problem??

Comment: the query isnt executing means there is a syntax error

Comment: Then show your error.

Comment: return me the same query that i wrote

Answer (score 0):

The correct query should look like this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM roll_header where contract_no like '%{$ContractNo}%' ORDER BY timedate DESC";
```

But, please make sure you sanitize your input (the `$ContractNo` variable).
Not sure what DB adapter you're using but here are the sanitization functions for [mysqli](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) and [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php).